# Update the data from spliced array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have splice the data and I want to update it's object from `disabled = true` to `disabled = false` ..  I have looking for another answer and cant find one..

Any Advice is appreciated. Thank you

this is my dropdown

```
const newDrop = [
  { key: "1", label: "Monthly GMV", sublabel: "Max.1" },
  { key: "2", label: "AOV", sublabel: "Max.1" },
  { key: "3", label: "Monthly Order", sublabel: "Max.1" },
  { key: "4", label: "Last Purchase", sublabel: "Max.1" },
  { key: "5", label: "Has Purchase" },
  { key: "6", label: "Has Purchase Spesific Product" },
  { key: "7", label: "Located In", sublabel: "Max.1" },
];
```

selected function : when selected the dropdown, it will add new attribute   `disabled:true`

```
newInput({ key }) {
    const {
      changeFormAttribute,
      form: { selectedDrop, newDrop, data },
    } = this.props;

    itemIndex = newDrop.map((itm) => {
      let x = itm.key === key;

      return x && itm.key !== "6" && itm.key !== "5" ? { ...itm, disabled: true } : { ...itm };
    });
    
    changeFormAttribute({
      newDrop: itemIndex,
    });
  }
```

delete function: this is onClick function, when clicked, it should splice the data, and check, if the spliced data have `disabled === true` change it to  `disabled:false` . the spliced have working properly, but not change the attribute to `disabled = false`

```
 deleteInput(index) {
    const {
      changeFormAttribute,
      form: { selectedDrop },
    } = this.props;
  
    let selected = selectedDrop || [];
    selected.splice(index, 1).map((e) => {return e.disabled === true ? false:true })

    changeFormAttribute({ selectedDrop: selected });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `splice` function not returning the element. You may need to change it to

```js
 selected.splice(index, 1).map((e) => {
     e.disabled === true ? false:true
     return e; 
 })
```